# Recommendations on low-fat foods for pancreatitis in dog?

Tags: dogs, health, diet

My 4 year old dog was recently diagnosed with pancreatitis.  My vet has made it sound as though this usually happens for a few reasons:

- The dog ate something weird/abnormal and it caused temporary inflammation
- For whatever reason, the dog is more vulnerable to pancreas inflammation and it will likely happen again if not kept on a proper diet

Since my dog hasn't had any changes in diet or gotten into anything, I'm leaning towards the latter being our reality.

I was instructed that the best treatment is a low-fat diet, and was sent home with prescription low-fat i/d food.  However, this food is expensive for someone on a low budget, and already providing additional medication to treat the dogs epilepsy.

Does anyone have any suggestions for cost effective, low-fat food diets for dogs?  Specifically with tendencies of pancreatitis?

### Edits to address comments

Our regular food regimen prior to this was Blue Buffalo: Chicken and Brown Rice, which he has eaten for the majority of his life.

I'm able to buy a 30lbs bag of Blue Buffalo for about $50, and the Hills Prescription food is about $35 for an 8lbs bag.

Comment: It would be helpful to explain what the dog is currently eating, low fat may simply be a comparison to what you're feeding. My friends dog with pancreatitis can only eat certain flavors of dog foods which have less fat. Ex Taste of the wild Prairie works for him but Salmon flavor does not.

Comment: @Tai you're definitely right!  I added this to the bottom of my post.  He has been on Blue Buffalo: Chicken and Brown Rice for majority of his life.

Comment: How much do you pay for blue buffalo vs ID dry? Also how many cups a day does your dog need of each?

Comment: @RebeccaRVT I'm able to buy a 30lbs bag of Blue Buffalo for about $50, and the Hills Prescription food is about $35 for an 8lbs bag.